An Element in Euclidean Domain is Prime if and only if Universal Side Divisor. (Is This True?)
Claim. (Is this true?) An element $u\in \text{Euclidean Domain }R$ is prime if and only if it denotes a universal side divisor.
Proof Attempt. Let $u\in \text{Euclidean Domain }R$ denote some arbitrary universal side divisor. Utilizing the property that (i) for all $a\in R$ there exists $z\in R_0^{\times}=R^{\times}\cup\{0\}$ such that $a=qu+z$ for some $q\in R$ (by definition of universal side divisor), and (ii) $[z]\in R/(u)$ denotes a unit if and only if $z\in R$ denotes a unit, then all non-zero elements of $R/(u)$ must be units according to the canonical homomorphism. (i.e. $R/(u)$ is a field.) Being that this is true for a Euclidean Domain if and only if $u$ is prime, we're done with the first direction.
In order to see the converse, let $p\in \text{Euclidean Domain }R$ denote some arbitrary prime element. Then $R/(p)$ is a field. Recalling the fact $[z]\in R/(u)$ denotes a unit if and only if $z\in R$ denotes a unit, we conclude that for all $a\in R$ there exists $z\in R_0^{\times}$ such that $a=qu+z$ for some $q\in R$. $\square$
Thank you for your time. It is very appreciated.

No, e.g. the usds of $,\Bbb Z,$ are $\pm2,,\pm3,,$ since $,2\not\equiv \pm1,0\pmod{!p},$ if $,|p|>3.\ \ $

@BillDubuque I'm sorry, seeing how easily you disproved this claim makes me realize I need to look for counter-examples more. I appreciate the help nonetheless. I presume the forward direction should still hold though? That is, USDs are necessarily prime? (p.s. If you want, just copy-and-paste your comment as an answer, and I'll mark it as the "Accepted Answer". Otherwise, I can just type up an answer myself with some additional information.)

Yes, usd $\Rightarrow$ prime, by  $\,p\,$ is a usd $\!\iff\!\! \,R/p\,$ has a complete system of  reps using only units of $R$ (and $0),\,$ hence $\,R/p\,$ is a field, e.g. $\,\Bbb Z/3 = \{-1,1,0\}.\,$
But prime $\not\Rightarrow$ usd, e.g.  the usds  of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ are $\,\pm2,\,\pm3,\,$ since $\,2\not\equiv \pm1,0\pmod{\!p}\,$ if $\,|p|>3$.
